# On cygwin I get errors containing -lintl and -liconv when running gcc

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I have installed cygwin and gcc but when I try to run "gcc hw.c" from the terminal I get these error messages:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lintl: No such file or directory

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -liconv: No such file or directory
```

Do you know how to fix them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install following two pacvkages :

```
libiconv-devel
libintl-devel
```

Comment: It worked, thanks for the fast reply!